# How to add the admin role to Drupal 7 after upgrading from Drupal 6?

Tags: updating, users

In Drupal 6 there was a module called Admin Role which allows you to make a superadmin role (same rights as superuser). This function is now in core (as of Drupal 7). So if you install Drupal 7, you get three roles by default: anonymous, authenticated, administrator.

However, when upgrading a site from D6 to D7, this new admin role is missing. How do I add this role or convert an existing custom role to be the admin role?

Comment: The core functionality doesn't always work.  To compensate, you still need [Admin Role](https://www.drupal.org/project/adminrole) in Drupal 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set an admin role in `admin/config/people/accounts` or by going to Configuration -> Account Settings under "People" label.

The help text under the select box says:

> This role will be automatically assigned new permissions whenever a module is enabled. Changing this setting will not affect existing permissions.

So remember to assign the existing permissions to this new role! But whenever a module is enabled and new permissions are created, this role will automatically be granted those.

To create new roles you go to People -> Permissions (tab) -> Roles (secondary tab)

Comment: Damn, beat me to the punch :p

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something simple. Accepted due to being faster.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a role that you want to be your second admin role, and then assign it as `admin/config/people/accounts`.

> This role will be automatically assigned new permissions whenever a
>   module is enabled. Changing this setting will not affect existing
>   permissions.

Comment: Thanks. +1 for the correct answer. Baysaa was just a tick faster, so I'm accepting his answer.